# How to find and return a column index in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a VBA code to clear some data from multiple excel files. The problem is that the positions of the headers are not fixed and the columns slip away when I put together the files. 
I have to find the column index based on header name and assign them to variables.

I declared the range of the header to a variable.
**How can I return the column index to a variable?** 
I have never done this before that is why I am asking you guys.
At my first attempt I was thinking something like this:

```
Set findrng = sourceWS.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 100))
index1 = findrng.Find("COUNTRY")
```

index1 should store an integer like 1 or 21 ...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused to what you are asking.

Is your problem that you would like to be able to search your first row for headers, and retrieve a specific column based on the header?

```
thisRow = 1

searchCol = Sheet1.Cells(thisRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="someString", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
```

? Then you can access that column with the `.column` accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Ah sorry guys I just found it. It was simple as hell...

```
ind1 = findrng.Find("COUNTRY").Column
```

Comment: Note that `.Find` will return `Nothing` whenever it doesn't find a match for what it's looking for: this code will throw run-time error 91 in these cases. You should **always** only ever access members of the result of a `Find` call *after* verifying that it contains a valid object reference, e.g. `If Not findrng Is Nothing Then`